# Multi User Web Application User Settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm currently working on a web application that has a lot of user settings. 
Things that can be displayed, graphics, statistics, coloring etc.

For example a setting would be something like (ItemID = 1, MyCutOff = $5.00, AlertColor=Red)
There are a lot of these different types of settings some more complicated than others.

Right now what I'm doing is on Login the users settings are read and stored in a DataTable which is stored in session, but I'm sure that is not best practice.

What is the best practice to deal with this ? I'd like to be as efficient as possible since the application has the possibility of having many concurrent users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use database to hold your session, then you read them from one table and you move them to some other table.

For me you can left them on the DataTable that you already have them and just ask for them when you need them.

Now one optimization that you can do in a page cycle is to [use the `HttpContext.Current.Items[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.100).aspx), for example if you load a parameter from your table and you need to use it on 20 different place in a page call (eg, inside custom controls, inside the master page, inside the page etc) you can use the `HttpContext.Current.Items[]` to store it.

There are also the [asp.net profile properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) that can be customized and used for your users.

Comment: atm session is stored in memory

Comment: ASP.NET profiles are probably the "clean" way to implement this.

Comment: Thanks what we're going to end up doing is using asp.net profile properties.

Answer (score 0):

If they are truly just settings ( things that determine the UI etc) you could also use localStorage. Really easy to stringify and parse json data in key value pairs using localStorage. As long as its not sensitive data. If you need to pass the params back server side this may not always be the best option but that's for you to decide as you know the project but may be worth a look.